# How to find out shared variables among functions by using LLVM API?

Tags: llvm

Recently I used LLVM API to test C++ program. Now I want to find out the shared variables among different functions, is there any way to do that? It seems that the [AliasAnalysis](http://llvm.org/docs/AliasAnalysis.html) doesn't work!

I write a Function Pass as following:

```
bool EscapeAnalysis::runOnFunction(Function& F) {
    EscapePoints.clear();

    TargetData& TD = getAnalysis<TargetData>();
    AliasAnalysis& AA = getAnalysis<AliasAnalysis>();
    Module* M = F.getParent();
 // errs() << *M << "\n";
 // Walk through all instructions in the function, identifying those that
 // may allow their inputs to escape.
    for(inst_iterator II = inst_begin(F), IE = inst_end(F); II != IE; ++II) {
        Instruction* I = &*II;

     // The most obvious case is stores.  Any store that may write to global
     // memory or to a function argument potentially allows its input to escape.
        if (StoreInst* S = dyn_cast<StoreInst>(I)) {
             Type* StoreType = S->getOperand(0)->getType();
             unsigned StoreSize = TD.getTypeStoreSize(StoreType);
             Value* Pointer = S->getPointerOperand();

             bool inserted = false;
             for (Function::arg_iterator AI = F.arg_begin(), AE = F.arg_end(); 
                  AI != AE; ++AI) {
                 if (!isa<PointerType>(AI->getType())) continue;
                 AliasAnalysis::AliasResult R = AA.alias(Pointer, StoreSize, AI, ~0UL);
                 if (R != AliasAnalysis::NoAlias) {
                     EscapePoints.insert(S);
                     inserted = true;
                     break;
                 }
            }

            if (inserted)
                continue;

            for (Module::global_iterator GI = M->global_begin(), GE = M->global_end();
                 GI != GE; ++GI) {
                errs() << *GI << "\n";
                AliasAnalysis::AliasResult R = AA.alias(Pointer, StoreSize, GI, ~0UL);
                errs() << "R: " << R << " , NoAlias: " << AliasAnalysis::NoAlias << "\n";

                if (R != AliasAnalysis::NoAlias) {
                    EscapePoints.insert(S);
                    break;
                }
            }

      // Calls and invokes potentially allow their parameters to escape.
      // FIXME: This can and should be refined.  Intrinsics have known escape
      // behavior, and alias analysis may be able to tell us more about callees.
        } else if (isa<CallInst>(I) || isa<InvokeInst>(I)) {
            EscapePoints.insert(I);

            // Returns allow the return value to escape.  This is mostly important
            // for malloc to alloca promotion.
        } else if (isa<ReturnInst>(I)) {
            EscapePoints.insert(I);

            // Branching on the value of a pointer may allow the value to escape through
            // methods not discoverable via def-use chaining.
        } else if(isa<BranchInst>(I) || isa<SwitchInst>(I)) {
            EscapePoints.insert(I);
        }

     // FIXME: Are there any other possible escape points?
    }

     return false;
}
```

---

Test the main.cpp as following:
    #include

```
using namespace std;

int X = 0;

int foo() {
X = 1;
int b = 1;
return 0;
}

int bar(int param) {
int y = X;
int z = 9;
int a = z;

++a;
return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

the global variable X is the shared variable between function bar and function foo.
But when I use the command as following to run the pass:

```
opt -load ./EscapeAnalysis.so -escape-analysis main.o | llc > main.ss
```

I get the result:

```
R: 1 , NoAlias: 0
```

all result are the same.
I print out the variables in escapePoint, find that variable a, z, y in function bar are in escapePoint. It is not right!

Note: I write a opt pass to test program.

Comment: Could you show precisely how you are using alias analysis? Also, are you looking for a way to find shared *variables* (which doesn't require alias analysis) or shared *memory* (which does)?

Comment: I have shown you how I use alias analysis, you can check it. Oh, yes! Do you say  it is not necessary to use alias analysis to find shared variables? I want to find out the shared variables among functions. such as the variable X between function bar and function foo above!But now I am not familiar with the LLVM API and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Alias analysis is required if you want to identify when two different variables might point to the same memory. If you just want to check which variables are shared with other functions in the same module, you can:

1. Iterate over all instructions, and for each:
2. Iterate over all its operands, and for each:
3. Check whether it's a `GlobalVariable` (via `isa`, for instance), and if so:
4. Iterate over all the global's uses (via `use_begin` and `use_end`), and for each:
5. Check whether it's an `Instruction`, and if so:
6. Retrieve the enclosing function (via `getParent()->getParent()`), and for that function:
7. Check whether it is the currently-processed function. If not, it means you found a variable shared between the current function and another function.

There are also other ways of checking this, for example going over all the globals in the current module.